# Obtaining exact path without filename

Tags: c#

I'm creating an extension for visual studio 2012 and am having a hard time finding the location of the arbitrary file that the extension is running behind. Does anyone have a good way of doing this through the extension? Maybe with reflection or some other sort of Path method?

Comment: Please try to describe a problem more clearly or add some example.

Comment: I need to change the look of my window with my extension depending on what directory I am in. The extension will need the pathname of the file I am working on in order to do so. however, this needs to work with any file that is being coded, read, ect in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string executingtitle = _applicationObject.Solution.FullName;
string[] title = executingtitle.Split( ',' );
string filename = title[0];
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
```

One of my co-workers helped me out. Here's the code for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Then you need to look at the the functions in Path to find the directory.  I think its one of these:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName
Path.GetPathRoot
```

Comment: when I do that it gives me the pathway of the extension not the pathway of the current file that the developer is working on. Essentially what I'm doing is changing the look of the main window, depending on what directory I am in. So I need the pathway of file not of the extension.

Comment: Ok, misunderstood what you were asking for.  Looks like you found the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the path extensions

Works great on https://dotnetfiddle.net/

- `using System.IO;`

```cs
var path = "/test/test2/test.txt";
Console.WriteLine($"GetFileName {Path.GetFileName(path)}");
Console.WriteLine($"GetFullPath {Path.GetFullPath(path)}");
Console.WriteLine($"GetDirectoryName {Path.GetDirectoryName(path)}");
// correct exact path without filename
Console.WriteLine($"dirPath {path.Substring(0, path.Length - Path.GetFileName(path).Length)}");

/*
Prints:
GetFileName test.txt
GetFullPath /test/test2/test.txt
GetDirectoryName /test/test2
dirPath /test/test2/
*/
```

### Note

- the path separator has to be native to your machine. E.g. `/test/test2/test.txt` won't work on windows while `\test\test2\test.txt` will